Mismatched Input Exception When Deserializing Empty Enum
I recently migrated my Spring Boot application from version 2.7.x to 3.0.x, and I'm encountering an issue when deserializing an enum field with an empty object value. The following code worked with Jackson 2.13, but it no longer works with Jackson 2.17. Please help me to create a custom deserializer that can handle any enum class. Thanks in advance
Constraints:

I cannot update the JSON structure or modify the POJO classes to include the @JsonDeserialize(using = xxx.class) annotation on the field, as these classes are provided by third parties.
I cannot use a regex approach like json.replace("{},", "").replace("{}", ""); to replace empty objects, as this method is used in many places and could potentially introduce risks.
I cannot register the module in the ObjectMapper individually for each enum class, as new classes may be added by third parties in the future, which could lead to failures.

Json :
{       
    "lineItems":[
        
        {},
        {}
    ]
}

Class:
@ToString
@Data
public class YourClass {

    private List<ItemEnum> lineItems;
    
}

ItemEnum class
public enum ItemEnum
{
    ITEM_1, ITEM_2, ITEM_3

}

Code:
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException
    {
      String json = "{\"lineItems\":{},{}]}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);
        objectMapper.coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Array)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyString, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyObject, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyArray, CoercionAction.AsNull);
        objectMapper.coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Collection)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyString, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyObject, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyArray, CoercionAction.AsNull);
        objectMapper.coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Enum)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyString, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyObject, CoercionAction.AsNull)
                .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.EmptyArray, CoercionAction.AsNull);
        YourClass obj = objectMapper.readValue(json, YourClass.class);
        System.err.println(obj);
}

Error:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.demo.ItemEnum` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 5, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.demo.YourClass["lineItems"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1767)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1446)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:958)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:361)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:246)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:310)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3848)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3816)
    at com.demo.Application.main(Application.java:57)


Since the POJO classes are provided by external team(third party) and you cannot modify them, please do try create your own EnumModule by extending SimpleModule and register your custom Deserialiser in the ctor addDeserializer(ItemEnum.class, new Xxx<>(ItemEnum.class)); Also register this module in objectMapper objectMapper.registerModule

There are many Enum classes So I need to write generic custom deserialiser which should work for deserializing any of the enum class. Can you help me with creating generic custom deserialiser
